# How to use the same eventhandler for different events

Tags: wpf, event-handling

How can i create events for a click on a textbox, a checkbox and combobox and use the same eventhandler for all these events?

Comment: Depending on what you indend to do, you may for example handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works! i didnt realise that MouseLeftButtonDown is a bubbling event...

Comment: How can i get the name of the textbox that triggered the event?

Comment: You just cast to the control type... ooops. You have multiple controls. You sure this is a good plan?

Comment: i just need a way to get to know the name of the clicked item

Comment: @pats `((FrameworkElement)sender).Name`. I think it's very likely that what you want to do with it is a bad idea, but that's how you get it.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? what would you suggest instead?

Comment: @pats I haven't seen your code, so I can't give you a very concrete answer. Of all the things I've seen people do with the names of controls as a string in WPF, IIRC all of them, so far, were better done with MVVM/bindings. But I haven't seen your specifics. Anyway, it may not be practical for you to rearchitect your whole application, so grab the names and see if you can get it working the way you intended.

Comment: `and use the same eventhandler for all these events` you don't; use an event trigger with event to command bindings...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you indend to do, you may for example handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(fe.Name);
}
```

**Sample XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="a" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown" />
<CheckBox x:Name="b" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown" />
<ComboBox x:Name="c" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```